# SQL count - not working

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I am trying this code:

```
SELECT COUNT (oferta_id_oferta) 
FROM `oferta_has_tags` 
WHERE oferta_id_oferta = 
(SELECT id_oferta FROM oferta 
WHERE oferta = "designer")
```

I receive `error: 1630 - FUNCTION mydb.COUNT does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual`

If I remove the `COUNT` word, I get two results.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Don't put a space

```
SELECT COUNT(oferta_id_oferta) 
FROM `oferta_has_tags` 
WHERE oferta_id_oferta = 
(SELECT id_oferta FROM oferta 
WHERE oferta = "designer")
```

Comment: GOD that's annoying.

Comment: couldn't believe it!

Comment: that is insane. it's 2021 and the parser can't handle that?

Answer (score 8):

Try removing the space between COUNT and the parentheses:

```
SELECT COUNT(oferta_id_oferta) 
FROM `oferta_has_tags` 
WHERE oferta_id_oferta = 
(SELECT id_oferta FROM oferta 
WHERE oferta = "designer")
```

Also, you can probably get rid of your subquery by joining:

```
SELECT COUNT(oferta_id_oferta) 
FROM `oferta_has_tags`, `oferta`
WHERE
    oferta_has_tags.oferta_id_oferta = oferta.id_oferta
    AND oferta.oferta = "designer"
```