# MySQL Join Query error, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have 3 tables:

- users
- items
- user_groups
- Each user can post multiple items to items table
- Each user has one record in user_groups which defines what user group he belongs to (e.g new users, junior users, senior users admins, etc)

I'm trying to get a list of the ids of the users who meet the following criteria:

- Belong to the user group '3'
- Have posted less than 5 items today

Here's my query:

```
SELECT u.id, COUNT (i.id) as numPosted
FROM users u, items i
    JOIN user_groups on user_groups.userId = u.id
    AND user_groups.groupId = '5'
 WHERE                          
     i.userId = u.id AND
     i.datePosted = CURDATE() AND                         
     numPosted < 5
```

- In the JOIN, its making sure the user belongs to the user group 5
- And in the Where its checking that the items belong to the userId, and the items where posted today, and the number of items posted was less than 5.

When I run this query, I get this error:

```
#1630 - FUNCTION items.COUNT does not exist. Check the 
'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `groupId = '3'` rather than 5? Is a `GROUP BY u.id` not needed? Also wonder if the space after the `COUNT` makes a difference?

Comment: Check the space. Apparently it causes problems. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840253/sql-count-not-working

Comment: @Glenn Bloody hell!! Yes, it was the space after Count! However, now its giving the error: `#1054 - Unknown column 'numPosted' in 'where clause'`. Any ideas about that?

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(i.id) < 5`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the space after `COUNT`, setting `groupId = '3'` (assuming groupId really is text), and adding a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT u.id, COUNT(i.id) as numPosted
  FROM users u
       JOIN user_groups g ON (g.userId = u.id AND g.groupId = '3')
       LEFT OUTER JOIN items i ON (i.userId = u.id and i.datePosted = CURDATE())
  GROUP BY u.id
  HAVING COUNT(i.id) < 5
```

There is also the question of capturing users who made no posts. Straight join and you will lose those users, an outer join will be needed in there.

Comment: Do I need to keep the `COUNT(i.id) as numPosted` in the first statement? The HAVING is enough for checking it

Comment: I'm getting `#1054 - Unknown column 'u.id' in 'on clause'` with this query

Comment: No, you can get rid of the `, COUNT(i.id) as numPosted` in the `SELECT` portion. I don't know what the columns in the `users` table are. Is there a `users.id`?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, CURDATE() returns the current date with an implicit time of 00:00:00. So if you say : CURDATE() == "2012-09-16 00:38:16" it will return 0 because CURDATE is "2012-09-16 00:00:00". You should use a BETWEEN statement: datePosted BEWEEN CURDATE() and NOW() (which implicitly indicates BETWEEN '2012-09-16 00:00:00' AND '2012-09-16 00:38:16').

You may try :

```
SELECT u.id, COUNT(i.id) as numPosted
FROM users u, items i
JOIN user_groups on user_groups.userId = u.id
AND user_groups.groupId = '3'
WHERE i.userId = u.id
AND i.datePosted BETWEEN CURDATE() AND NOW()
AND numPosted < 5
```

You can also use a > CURDATE() which is the exact same thing in a normal case, because if today(curdate) is 2012-09-16, every entry next to it will be today (but this is safer to use the previous query because if you use external services to recover / insert data, it may be something in the future...)

```
SELECT u.id, COUNT(i.id) as numPosted
FROM users u, items i
JOIN user_groups on user_groups.userId = u.id
AND user_groups.groupId = '3'
WHERE i.userId = u.id
AND i.datePosted > CURDATE()
AND numPosted < 5
```

Comment: The `datePosted` column is a date, not a datetime, so that's not the problem. The date will be matched. The problem is the error that im getting with the COUNT()