# MySQL error- COUNT does not exist, error 1630

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been working in mySQL and I have been having issues with the COUNT function. I have already tried removing the spaces and the error persists.

```
SELECT COUNT(payment) FROM paymentType
GROUP BY payment 
ORDER BY  COUNT (payment) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

I am trying to find the most common `payment` entry in the table `paymentType`.

Comment: "having issues" You should tell us exactly what you are trying to do, what you have tried, and show the results as text in the question with an [edit]. See [ask].

Comment: "the error persists".  What error???  How are we suppose to help you if we don't know what's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL count - not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840253/sql-count-not-working)

Comment: Try removing the space between `COUNT` and `(payment)` on line 3

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
select *
from (
  select payment, count(*) as c from paymentType group by payment
) x
order by c desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Close, but I think you meant to include `group by` in the inner query...

Comment: @sgeddes Oh, yes. Thanks. Added the missing `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the most common payment, then I think you want:

```
SELECT payment
FROM paymentType
GROUP BY payment 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked wonderfully and helped me out with the base for a few other queries I needed to write!

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
SELECT Count(payment),payment FROM paymentType
GROUP BY payment 
ORDER BY  COUNT DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Note: the column you will get after the COUNT function will be a new column… And it has to have a name – so SQL automatically names it “count” (check the latest screenshot above). When you refer to this column in your ORDER BY clause, you have to use this new name

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the space in `HAVING` clause between `COUNT` and `(`

Try this:

```sql
ORDER BY COUNT(payment) DESC
```

[Count aggregate function SQL](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-aggregate-functions/sql-count/)